# Want to send mail in Python with content of file as it is just like same in text file and file content into a variable

Tags: python

I want to send a mail with file (baba.txt) content as it is which present in file format using Python script.

For example:

```
this is python course.


line of code.


Thank...you....
```

Want same above format in mail as well. When I am trying to execute my script, it put in a single line in my mail like below

```
this is python course.line of code.Thank you
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import smtplib, ssl
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
a=str(os.popen('cat baba.txt').read())
print("""a""")

sender_email = "asdf@gmail.com"
receiver_email = "myeamil@gmail.com"
password = ""
receiver_email_bcc = "sdfg@gmail.com"
receiver_email_bcc1 = "sdfg@gmail.com"
message = MIMEMultipart("alternative")
message["Subject"] = "Output of linux command"
message["From"] = sender_email
message["To"] = receiver_email
message["Bcc"] = receiver_email_bcc
message["Bcc"] = receiver_email_bcc1

html = """
<html>
  <body>
    <p>Hi Team,<br>
       server output command <br>
       Below are the out put of below commands: %s <br>

        <br>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
"""%(a,)

part1 = MIMEText(text, "plain")
part2 = MIMEText(html, "html")


message.attach(part1)
message.attach(part2)
try:
    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
    server.ehlo()
    server.login(sender_email,password)
    server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message.as_string())
    server.close()

    print ('Email sent!')
except:
    print ('Email not sent!')
```

I want to send a mail with (baba.txt) file content as it is which present in file format using Python script including multiple line space, tab and white space.

Comment: That's just how whitespace is handled in HTML, you need to use `&nbsp;` and `<br>`, or use `pre` and `code` elements.

Comment: NO not HTML one ..

Comment: there is file for example baba.txt.

Comment: under baba.txt it is written line

Lets say i have a variable called foo and i have the string "this is foo"

So
foo = "this is foo"
    #that is the variable that has been initised

 #now lets print it.

=============
if run my code all multiple line come into single line.

Comment: I understand that. But the email you're sending *is* HTML, so you need to adapt the content for that. Or have it in HTML format in the file, too.

Comment: can you modify my code and which help me to understand .. i am very new to python. If you want delete html tag you can delete it. I want out put as per my example.

Comment: This isn't really a Python problem. Your email is in HTML. You're putting content with plain whitespace (`" "`, `"\n"`, `"\t"` in Python) into it and, for whatever reason, expecting it to retain that formatting. It doesn't work on a web page, it won't work in an HTML email. Either send plain text emails, format the text file content correctly, or write something to replace the plain text formatting with appropriate HTML entities. But no, I'm not writing this for you.

Comment: now i got it Thank you very much

Comment: I am able to attach the file and send it via outlook using smtplib module, My question is do we have the workaround to directly show the content of the attachments directly in the main body ?? Instead of attaching the file in the mail??? Could someone please help suggest!